# Why does Bpf allow ether[0:2] and ether[0:4] but not ether[0:3]?

Tags: networking, wireshark, packet-sniffers, bpf

Why does Berkeley Packet Filter allow filtering on ether[0:2] and ether[0:4] but not ether[0:3] which is the vendor?`tcpdump 'ether[0:3] = 0x000000'` returns with
`tcpdump: data size must be 1, 2, or 4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is confirmed by the [pcap-filter](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html) man page (search for “byte offset”), although it does not provide additional information either.

My guess would be that libpcap [refuses](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/blob/8795ed44290a462bcd1129a4b85fccb5d2094d76/gencode.c#L7286) to create a program that compares three bytes at a time because the classic BPF programs it generates [do not have instructions](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0/source/Documentation/networking/filter.txt#L204) to directly support such comparisons. It can load one byte, one half-word (two bytes) or one word (four bytes) into one of the registers and compare it to a value, but it is not able to work with three-byte long values.

I suppose the workaround would be to compare the value in two steps, `ether[0:2]` then `ether[2]`.